# redux/toolkit combining actions, reducers, and services, for authentication and login

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

New to React, first attempt at building anything related to authentication. After following the Redux tutorial, I've seen it uses the reduxjs/toolkit to combine actions, reducers, and services using `createSlice`, `createAsyncThunk`, etc. All the tutorials I've read on authentication / login don't follow this pattern, and I can't wrap my head around setting up the `initialState` for authentication, users, and JWT. Is it possible to combine actions, reducers, and services into a "slice" or is it better to keep them separate?
The closest guide to what I want uses `redux-thunk`as a middleware, but if my app is already using redux/toolkit.
Any ideas how to go from this:

```
//_service auth.service.js
const login = (username, password) => {
    //return JSON object 
    //Response: { "token": "lkjdfs9876fd", "user": "username", "type": "partner", "customer": "servicetrace" }
    return axios.post(API_URL, 'signin', {
        username,
        password
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if(response.data.accessToken){
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data))
        }
        return response.data;
    })  
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};

//_reducer auth.js
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

const initialState = user
? { isLoggedIn: true, user }
: { isLoggedIn: false, user: null };

export default function (state = initialState, action){
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch (type) {
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
          return {
            ...state,
            isLoggedIn: true,
            user: payload.user,
          };
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
          return {
            ...state,
            isLoggedIn: false,
            user: null,
          };
        case LOGOUT:
          return {
            ...state,
            isLoggedIn: false,
            user: null,
          };
        default:
          return state;
    }
}

//_actions auth.js
export const login = (username, password) => (dispatch) => {
    return AuthService.login(username, password)
    .then(
        (data) => {
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: { user: data }
            });

            return Promise.resolve();
        },
        (error) => {
            const message = (
                error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
                error.message ||
                error.toString();

                dispatch({
                    type: LOGIN_FAIL,
                });

                dispatch({
                    type: SET_MESSAGE,
                    payload: message
                });
            
                return Promise.reject();
        }
    );
};
```

into a single slice:

```
//authSlice.js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: null,
    token: null,
    error: null
}

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
        //    
        },
        loginFailure: (state, action) => {
        //
        }
    },
    extraReducers:{}
});

export default authSlice.reducer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd transform the reducer to the slice, but keep the thunks as they are. The redux-thunk middleware is already included with redux toolkit, so you can directly use them - but they still need to be defined outside your slice.

You can also replace this hand-written thunk by one created with `createAsyncThunk`, but I'd first try to get this up & running and then take a look at the docs (or even better yet, the [Async Logic and Data Fetching](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic) part of the official essentials tutorial) and refactor it over to cAT after that. No need to do everything at once.